# How to maintain previous state value(currentPage) and then reduce offset value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
gridperPage: 12,
  listperPage: 8,
  currentPage: 1,
  perPage: 3,


  page() {

    let offset = (this.currentPage * this.gridperPage)
    let accToken = localStorage && localStorage.loggedinUser ? localStorage.loggedinUser : null;
    
    const categoryUrl = project_key + `/product-projections/search?offset=${offset}&limit=${this.gridperPage}`;

    const sendGetRequest = async() => {

      let access_token = await axios.request({
        method: "get",
        baseURL: categoryUrl,
        headers: {
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + accToken,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: {}
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          // this.productsList = response.body;
          this.productsList = response.data.results;
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(this.productsList);
        }

      });




    };

    sendGetRequest();
  },
```

```html
<b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" @change="page"></b-pagination>
```

How to decrease offset value to 12 when trying to decrease page value, That is need to maintain previous state value(currentPage) and then reduce offset value.

now when i click on page2 i am getting for page 2 offset(12) limit(12), page 3 offset(24) limit(12).

i want to reduce offset value by 12, when user click on page 2 from page 3

Answer (score 0):

Setup a watcher that watches the `currentPage`. If the `currentPage` is greater than 1 and less than the previous `currentPage` value (prior to changing), decrement the offset by 12.

```
watch: {
  currentPage: function (newPage, oldPage) {
    this.offset = newPage < oldPage && newPage >= 1 ? this.offset - 12 : this.offset
  }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to define oldPage and newPage value in data, ?

Comment: The code provided in the question is behaving like, WHen moving to page 2 and page3, offset and limit is incrementing as expected, But when moving backwards direction then also it is incrementing..

Comment: You do not define the values in `data`. They are provided as function arguments to the watcher of `currentValue`.

Comment: I have defined watch property and added code.

But it is not passing to that, Is it  possible to  add it in page() method?

currentPage: function (newPage, oldPage) {
    this.offset = newPage < oldPage && newPage >= 1 ? this.offset - 12 : this.offset
  }

Comment: No. The `watch` property is defined on the Vue component as a top level property. It cannot be nested.

Comment: Any suggestions please, I placed watch property, But it is not working. When moving to page 2 from page3, offset and limit is incrementing as expected, But when moving backwards direction then also it is incrementing. So with out using watch, is there any alternatives that we can do it in  this condition let offset = (this.currentPage * this.gridperPage)